# What are the charges if I host my chatbot in apps exchange

Tags: bootstrap, python, ruby-on-rails

I have build a chatbot on python, what would be the cost to host it on Salesforce 
 Apps Exchange

Comment: You can only add Salesforce Apps to AppExchange. And the costs depends if your app is free or paid (in which case you will have to pay for the Security Review)

Answer (score 1):

You can only create and upload an App to the App Exchange that is based on Salesforce (Standard objects, fields, Visualforce pages, apex controllers, lightning components, etc), which doesn't support Python. The closest you are going to be able to get is by creating an app that is communicating with your python server.

If your app is going to be a paid app, the main cost might be the Security Review, but there are also listing fees, etc. The costs of the Security Review, as mentioned in the FAQ [here](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Security_Review#z), are as follows:

> Q: Is there a fee?
>   A: There is a one-time upfront fee, and a small subsequent annual fee for this process. The initial Security Review fee is $2,700 USD for each paid app submitted (no fee for free apps). This includes the annual listing fee of $150 USD for the first year. If you have questions, speak with your Partner Account Manager about Security Review fees.
>
> Q: How much is the security review fee for Lightning Components?
>   A: If your package only contains Lightning Components, you are eligible for a discount of $1900, which means your security review fee will only be $800! If you have additional questions or concerns, please  submit this case.